# Can't load image in JavaFX using Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans

Here is my Code:

```
package week7;

import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;

/**
 * This application demonstrates a VBox.
 */
public class VBoxExample extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

private Label usernameLbl;
private TextField usernameTf;
private PasswordField passwordPf;
private Button loginBtn;
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    // Create the leaves
    usernameLbl = new Label("Username:");
    usernameTf = new TextField();
    passwordPf = new PasswordField();
    loginBtn = new Button("Login");
    imageView = new ImageView("file: flower.png");

    // Create a branch
    VBox vBox = new VBox(10);
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(usernameLbl, usernameTf, passwordPf, loginBtn, imageView);

    // Set the scene, show the stage
    stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
    stage.setTitle("VBox example");
    stage.show();
}
}
```

I try to put an image under the VBox window with this code:

```
imageView = new ImageView("file: flower.png");
```

The program works but there is no image displayed. I create my project in FXDemo1(project) - week7(package) - VBoxExample(class). And I already tried to put the image file into the week7 package or add it into the build folder. I even tried to create a folder named resources under /src, but none of them works.

And using file: flower.png is the only way the program will work, I also tried to  use /flower.png or /resources/flower.png, but they will cause an error.

Please tell how to load the image on Netbeans. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of the ImageView constructor is supposed to be a URL string. Instead of fiddling arround with the strings you should just create a File like this and get the URL from it.

```
imageView = new ImageView(new File("flower.png").toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```

This assumes the file is located in the working directory where your program is executed.

Comment: If the file is in the right place and is not corrupt this will work. You can test the first condition via File file = new File(...); if (file.canRead()) ... If this test fails the file is in the wrong place or is not readable.